# Redis is there a decr if feature

Tags: multithreading, redis

In my business application, I plan to store user balance in Redis cache server, allowing multiple processes to consume the balance. But the moment the amount falls to 0, I want the processes to "fail" consuming the balance.

As of now, I am not able to achieve this. For example, let us say the balance is 1 INR or $, and each of 2 threads want to consume it. Each thread does get and decr. So sometimes it is happening that the value is falling below 0, since there is no atomic operation like "DECR IF" similar to "compare and set".

Is it possible to achieve this in any other manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't a single command in Redis to do that, you can use its [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) with the [WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/watch) command for this purpose. The following pseudo from the *Optimistic locking using check-and-set* subsection is basically the answer to your question:

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```